# How to find the eigenvalues of a matrix with largest complex component?

Tags: matrices, spectral-norm

Is there an algorithm (cheaper than solving the whole eigenspectrum) that determines the eigenvalue(s) of a (non-hermitian) matrix with the largest (magnitude of) complex component?

I have not found any online. Though, I saw a few nice algos that can determine the eigenvalues with largest magnitude.

Physical background of this problem is shown in arxiv 2003.03039:
[image]

More generally, is there an algo that can solve the eigenvalue with largest component on an arbitrary direction on the complex plane?

Any discussion is welcomed; maybe this is achievable on some particular matrices? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know how to do this along any particular direction then you can multiply by the appropriate phase to do it along any other direction.

Comment: Do we get to assume the matrices are normal?

Comment: Go forward if you got something that works for normal matrices.